# Making a set from dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I want to create a set from the values of an existing dict

```
def function(dictionary):
    ... 
    return set_of_values
```

Say my dictionary looks like this: `{'1': 'Monday', '2': 'Tuesday', '3': 'Monday'}`

I want a set returned that only contains the unique values, like this:

```
{'Monday', 'Tuesday'}
```

Answer (score 21):

For Python:

```
set(d.values())
```

Equivalent on Python 2.7:

```
set(d.viewvalues())
```

If you need a cross-compatible Python 2.7/3.x code:

```
{d[k] for k in d}
```

Comment: One minor thing: In 2.7, `viewvalues` may be faster than `itervalues`. And it's also more consistent with the 3.x behavior. But then of course your code doesn't work in 2.6 and earlier.

Comment: @abarnert What'd you think of `set(my_dict[k] for k in my_dict)`... Think that should work pretty much everywhere...

Comment: @JonClements: Nick Coghlan has a nice blog post suggesting that the right way to write code that needs to be efficient in 2.x and 3.x is to write a wrapper (or find one in an existing project like `six` or `modernize`), then just use that. Yeah, it's a top-level function instead of a method, but who cares? So, `set(viewvalues(my_dict))`.

Comment: @JonClements: I don't actually know off the top of my head if `six` has a `viewvalues`, but I'm sure it has at least `itervalues`, or your own wrapper takes about 30 seconds, like [this](http://pastebin.com/u0tAPv0Y).

Comment: @abarnert I believe I've read that. I was just throwing that one in there as `values()`/`itervalues()` and `viewvalues()` had been mentioned - the only other option would have been a set-comp (but that's 2.7 like the view* methods)

Comment: how would a set comprehension change anything, still need to access the values

Comment: @wim `{my_dict[k] for k in my_dict}` '- true you've got a `__getitem__` overhead, but at least you don't have a "guess the right method"

Comment: same as your first comment, just without the function call

Comment: @wim except the set and gen-exp doesn't require 2.7+

Answer (score -1):

Just another way to unique out:

```
 >>> my_dict = {'1': 'Monday', '3': 'Monday', '2': 'Tuesday'}
 >>> {y:x for x,y in my_dict.iteritems()}.keys()
 ['Tuesday', 'Monday']
 >>>
```

Comment: why he needs set is just to unique out the values right ?

Comment: Depends how you interpret: *What I want is a set*... followed by an example of a `set` literal...

Comment: Why would you build a reverse dict where the values don't matter, just to use it as a fake set, just to copy the keys out of that into a dict?

Comment: thats why i mention "Just another way to unique out:"

Comment: But it's not really another way, it's just an obfuscated and inefficient variation of the same thing. Your dict uses a hash table exactly the same way as wim's set, except that yours also fills in the values of that hash table for no reason. If you want an actual "another way", you can, e.g., sort and throw away equal adjacent values (which might be useful if, e.g., the values weren't hashable—although given that the OP wants a set, that can't be an issue here).